# Duty Cycle and Filtering in Switching Power Supplies

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, pulse, duty-cycle

I have a few confusions to clear up. The first one is about the switching power supply.
Does the power supply simply work on the bases of the duty cycle? Like If I have a pulsating signal of 50% duty cycle and I filter that out using a capacitor so the output should be 2.5V in case of giving a 5V.
Is the reason the fact that the capacitor charges and discharges according to the duty cycle?
And is the same thing used in the switching power supply?

Comment: Yes, with some fluxuation due to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite that simple, but for a buck converter it is almost that simple.

The key parts you are correct about is that, yes, there are switches, and yes, the PWM duty cycle goes a long way to determining the ratio of the input and output voltages.  What you're leaving out is that the switches feed an inductor, which smooth out the current from the switching before feeding the capacitor.

[this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80093/buck-converter-operation) has some answers for what happens next.